# The meaning of .[rep(token, nrow(.)), ] in R

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out Julia Silge's code for finding nearest neighbors to any given example in using word embeddings. Here is the [book](https://smltar.com/embeddings.html) where the code is used. I can make the code work with my data, I just do not understand one line of it.

The code is:

```
nearest_neighbors <- function(df, token) {
  df %>%
    widely(
      ~ {
        y <- .[rep(token, nrow(.)), ]
        res <- rowSums(. * y) / 
          (sqrt(rowSums(. ^ 2)) * sqrt(sum(.[token, ] ^ 2)))
        
        matrix(res, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(x = names(res)))
      },
      sort = TRUE
    )(item1, dimension, value) %>%
    select(-item2)
}
```

My problem is with this line `y <- .[rep(token, nrow(.)), ]`. I understand that dot here is a kind of pronoun for the whole dataframe, and that square brackets are used for indexing.  But if I try this line outside the bigger function, I obtain a huge NA table.

Here is my code:

```
tidy_pmi %>% .[rep("πρότερος", nrow(.)), ]
```

And the result I get is a large table of NAs.

When I use it inside `widely()` everything works fine. Any ideas what might be going on here? Is there another way to code this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your code does not make a lot of sense: you are selecting rows based on a character vector. This means that you want to select the row with a given row name, `"πρότερος"`, and you want to do this `nrow(.)` times. But your table doesn’t contain any row names, so the result is that you are selecting a non-existent row `nrow(.)` times.

Comment: That is exactly what I am asking: what does this line of code in Julia Silge's code achieve? It does not make much sense to me, either, and I reproduced it separately to figure it out. The `tidy_word_vectors` she gives to the function (see here https://smltar.com/embeddings.html) does not have rownames, either

Comment: If `token` was a row number or row name, `y` would become a dataframe of the same shape as `df` but containing repetitions of that row.  If you don't have row names, you'll get the `NA` values you saw.  You always have row numbers, and will only get `NA` if it is out of range for `df`.

Comment: That's the thing. In the examples from the book, token is always a string, and df is always a tibble (hence no rownames). This is really a puzzle how (and why) this code works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to solve problems like this is to try them out in a debugger.  A simple way to do that is to insert a call to `browser()` in the function that's doing the thing you don't understand, e.g.

```
nearest_neighbors <- function(df, token) {
  df %>%
    widely(
      ~ {
        browser()
        y <- .[rep(token, nrow(.)), ]
        res <- rowSums(. * y) / 
          (sqrt(rowSums(. ^ 2)) * sqrt(sum(.[token, ] ^ 2)))
        
        matrix(res, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(x = names(res)))
      },
      sort = TRUE
    )(item1, dimension, value) %>%
    select(-item2)
}
```

In the book, this is used as

```
tidy_word_vectors %>%
  nearest_neighbors("error")
```

Now I was too impatient to calculate `tidy_word_vectors`, which depends on `tidy_pmi`, which takes hours to compute.  So I computed a tiny version of `tidy_pmi` by using only 10 documents instead of 100000.  Following through with the calculations, `tidy_word_vectors` does end up with row names, but that's not what `.` is here:  it's some matrix which looks like this:

```
Browse[1]> str(.)
 num [1:255, 1:100] -0.0298 -0.0727 -0.0396 -0.0397 -0.0331 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:255] "1" "1.00" "12" "13" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:100] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
Browse[1]> rownames(.)
  [1] "1"             "1.00"          "12"            "13"            "2"             "2019"          "21.00"        
  [8] "2300.00"       "5"             "605b"          "7"             "a"             "about"         "access"       
 [15] "account"       "accounts"      "act"           "address"       "addresses"     "after"         "afterwards"   
 [22] "agency"        "all"           "am"            "amount"        "amounts"       "an"            "and"
   ...
```

etc.

That's because the `widely()` function modifies its input (`df`, in this case) into the matrix that becomes `.`.

So it really is using rownames to do the selection, and `y` becomes a matrix of the same shape as `.` but containing repetitions of the row named `"error"`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and for the very useful browser() trick I did not know! This does answer my question. 

In the meantime, I have found a more readable (though a much slower) way to calculate cosine similarity between vectors, which gives exactly the same result. Thanks to this -- and to your very helpful explanation -- I now fully understand what this code does, hurray)